# How to output JSON from Pentaho xaction?

Tags: ajax, json, pentaho

What's the best way to get a Pentaho xaction to return it's output in JSON format?

I have a dashboard that is driven by Pentaho xactions that return HTML fragments (tables) that I then insert into the page. It works okay, but I would like my xactions to return JSON instead of the HTML fragments to make things a bit more flexible and reusable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a sample available here

http://sandbox.pentaho.com/api-integration-samples/

Let us know how you do

Mike Tarallo
Sales Engineering Director
Pentaho

Comment: I had no idea that the Template Component had that kind of functionality.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, for anyone with the same issue: the json example in the download referenced above is action_sequences/json_map_data_no_js.xaction

Comment: Hi, I am not able to find 'template component' anywhere in design studio. I can see only 'Message Template' component. Is it same as 'Template Component'?

Comment: The URL in your answer is no longer valid.  Thanks.

Comment: there is no sandbox available now, why? @Micheal Tarallo

Answer (score 3):

Chuck,

There are several ways to go about adding a service to the Pentaho BIServer (which is what I assume you are doing if you are wanting to return JSON).  Which one to use depends on how much Java you know and how deep you want to get into the inner workings.

Option a: Write an xaction that uses the JavaScriptRule component.  You can pretty much do whatever you want with the JavaScript you write there, including writing whatever you wish to the http repsonse.  This is probably the quickest, but perhaps dirties and least maintainable way to accomplish what you want

Option b: Write a BIServer plugin.  One of the many facets of BIServer plugins you can write is to do this very thing, plug in a new kind of service.  Many of the community contributed plugins do this very thing.  Look at pentaho-cda for example (http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-cda/).  For info on how to write a BIServer plugin, see http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Developing+Plugins.  Within option b, you need to be mindful of which version of the BIServer you wish to deploy to since the plugin api changes a bit from release to release.  The short story here is if you are planning to deploy to 3.7 or earlier, you want to write a ContentGenerator.  If you can hold off till the next major release (aka Sugar), then you have nicer things at your disposal like the ability to plugin an actual HttpServlet or even a JaxRS annotated class (see the wiki doc).

Finally, ##pentaho in freenode IRC is a great place to come to with questions.

Hope this helps,
Aaron